# Typescript: calling static methods in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, static-methods

here is an example of my class with the methods in question

```
class Example {
    constructor(info) {
        // call validateInfo(info)
    }

    static validateInfo(info):void {
        // validate the info
    }
```

I would like to call validateInfo in the constructor, but I can't just do this with `this.validateInfo(info)` because it is a static method.

In Javascript, I could do this:

```
    constructor(info) {
        this.constructor.validateInfo(info)
    }
```

but, in Typescript this gives the following error:

`error TS2339: Property 'validateInfo' does not exist on type 'Function'.`

I understand the error message, but is there a Typescript equivalent for the Javascript solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a subclass may have called the constructor, not `Example`. I'd reference `Example` specifically:

```
constructor(info) {
    Example.validateInfo(info)
}
```

Another option to consider would be making it a normal method rather than a static method.